# Redirecting during fetch epic with redux-observables and RxJS

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router, redux-observable, connected-react-router

I have a fetch Epic that may return a 401 or 403 if the user doesn't have access to a server-side resource. I want to redirect during this Epic if this is the case.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
export const fetch$ = <T = any>(req: IRequest) =>
    from(performFetch<T>(req)).pipe(
        switchMap(res => of(res)),
        catchError(e => {
            if (e.status === 401 || e.status === 403) {
                window.location.replace(`/login?fwd=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)}`);
                return NEVER;
            }
            return of(e);
        })
    );
```

Where `performFetch` is just a simple function that does the fetch and returns a promise.

I'm using `window.location.replace` and so far it's working fine, but someone told me that it would mess up React.

I tried using `connected-react-router` and return a `push` action, but it wasn't doing the redirect.

Am I safe to continue doing it this way, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a need to use `window.location.replace` so as you have installed `react-router` or `connected-react-router`, which handles component navigation within your application.

You can consider using either `replace` or `push`.

If you wish the return the action, you will have to wrap it using an [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) operator.

```
import { replace } from 'connected-react-router'.

export const fetch$ = <T = any>(req: IRequest) =>
  from(performFetch<T>(req)).pipe(
    switchMap(res => of(res)),
    catchError(e => {
      if (e.status === 401 || e.status === 403) {
        of(replace(`/login?fwd=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)}`));
      }
      return of(e);
    })
  );
```

Or, you can simply call `replace`/`push` as a side-effect, while returning something else.

```
export const fetch$ = <T = any>(req: IRequest) =>
  from(performFetch<T>(req)).pipe(
    switchMap(res => of(res)),
    catchError(e => {
      if (e.status === 401 || e.status === 403) {
        replace(`/login?fwd=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)}`);
        return NEVER;
      }
      return of(e);
    })
  );
```

Comment: This is not working, and it might be because of my other code. I can see my state tree has the router in it, so that's there. The second example you gave seems to do nothing. The first one returns an action, but it's caught by my other epic which is calling fetch$, and it thinks that action is the fetch response.

Comment: ahh I see.. In that case, the first example might lead you closer to something. What is happening in the other code you stated?